# How to create non spatial index for geopackage data?

Tags: qgis, gdal, geopackage, index

I know QGIS/GDAL can create a spatial index for data in a geopackage. But what about non spatial data, how do I create an index for a non spatial data column using QGIS/GDAL for a geopackage data set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To stay within QGIS you can use [DB Manager](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/databases/db_manager.html). Just connect the GeoPackage to your [DB-Manager](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_db_manager.html) via right click on `"GeoPackage" -> "New Connection..."` and then open the `SQL` Window. Use a query such as:

```
CREATE INDEX myindex ON testgeopackage (mycolumn1, mycolumn2)
```

[image]

Comment: While using the DB Manager I also noticed the "Table"->"Edit Table"  table properties window has an Index pane with the option to create the index.

Answer (score 8):

With ogrinfo https://gdal.org/programs/ogrinfo.html

```
ogrinfo -sql "CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_name (column1, column2,columnN...)" my_geopackage.gpkg
```